# best way to Miss values null in Select LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I try get values of IEnumerable, I need modify default return of Select and need to discard null values.

In this function i work with XElement objects for this ".Elements()". 
I need that this function has the best performance possible, so for that I use  `Select(x => { }..)` in my code.

```
.Select(versiones =>
{
      var last= versiones.Elements().Last();
      if (last.condition)
      {
          var foo = bar(last);
          return new
          {
           Last = last,
           Foo = foo
          };
      }
   return null; // i need change it
})
```

The fundamental "problem" is when i create this code my result is:

**IEnumerable content:**

```
0[{Last=...,Foo=...}]
1 null
2 null
3 null
4 null
5[{Last=...,Foo=...}]
...
```

And i need used it for clear:

```
.Where(element=> element != null)
```

or

```
.RemoveAll(null)
```

not is best option, not like another cycle in my ienum.

I want to return:

```
0[{Last=...,Foo=...}]
1[{Last=...,Foo=...}]
2[{Last=...,Foo=...}]
3[{Last=...,Foo=...}]
4[{Last=...,Foo=...}]
5[{Last=...,Foo=...}]
```

Comment: If you removing the line `return null;`, you're getting any error. So, only the data which is in if will get returned. Null values will not come in you are output.

Answer (score 3):

You can get rid of `null` at all.
Based on you sample, where `condition` requires "last" element, you can simplify it to

```
var result = document.Elements()
    .Select(versiones => versiones.Elements().Last())
    .Where(last => last.condition)
    .Select(last => new
    {
        Last = last,
        Foo = bar(last)
    })
    .ToList();
```

You don't need to worry about amount of `Where` or `Select` functions, collection will be enumerated only once.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental problem is that you are using `Select` to filter elements, when `Where` should be used. Since you don't know which elements could be `null` before the `Select` call, it's best to just use:

```
.Select(...)
.Where(x => x != null);
```

Note that, unlike the second example with `RemoveAll`, the filters ran inside `Where` will be evaluated in the same loop as the `Select` call.

Comment: "The fundamental problem is that you are using Select to filter elements, when Where should be used. " , it is correct.. I revised my code and now i do:

where(condition).Select(...)

But im not sure if is the best solution.
"condition" realy is : last.AnyThing

And i need use "last" var in both of them, .Select and .Where .

Comment: @pikamorfo No, that's not the best way, at all. There's a reason I put the Where *after* the Select

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you don't need. Anyway there will be just one traversing on the collection.

Why?

Because LINQ expressions are **lazy**; In fact, the following code

```
var l = ...;
var l2 = l.Select(i => i.ToString()).Where(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i));
```

Does not traverses the array even one time!

Each LINQ operator returns an `IEnumerable<T>` which only when iterating throught it, retrieve its result. Except three cases:

1) A LINQ operator which returns a special collection (`List<T>`, an array) is used. For example, `ToList()`, `ToArray()`, etc.

2) A `foreach` loop executed on the result, then each item is retrieved when it is requested.

3) A count or sum operator is used (an operator that return just one result), for example, `Count()`, `Average()`, `Aggerate()`, etc.

To understand how this works, let's see an optional possible implementation of `Select()`:

```
public IEnumerable<TOutput> Select<TInput, TOutput>(this IEnumerable<TInput> source, Func<TInput, TOutput> selector)
{
    return new SelectEnumerable(source, selector);
}
```

The magic happens in the `SelectEnumerable` class:

```
private class SelectEnumerable<TInput, TOutput> : IEnumerable<TOutput>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<TInput> _Source;
    private readonly Func<TInput, TOutput> _Selector;

    public SelectEnumerable(IEnumerable<TInput> source, Func<TInput, TOutput> selector)
    {
        this._Source = source;
        this._Selector = selector;
    }

    public IEnumerator<TOutput> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (TInput item in _Source)
        {
            yield return _Selector(item);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
}
```

This method has many advantages, such as:

1) Many times, initialization code must be executed fast. For example, in a WPF application, code in view-models constructors freezes the GUI until its finishes. So, it's good to save it to another thread, for example. With lazy executing your LINQ expressions won't take time in the bulding.

2) When executing a code from a database, for example, it'll be very not smart to retrieve all the rows, then filter them in the memory... LINQ to SQL (and similary with other classes LINQ to Entities) uses `IQueryable<T>` to build SQL queries from expression trees, then send them to DBs. Thus, although the following codes are very similar, they have very different effencies:

```
var x = db.ToList().Where(r => r.Id < 555);
// Versus
var x = db.Where(r => r.Id < 555).ToList();
```

The first send query like `SELECT * FROM [db]` then filters the result in memory, but the second send query like `SELECT * FROM [db] WHERE [Id] < 555` then converts the result to `List<T>`.